# HTML to PDF converter

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, pdf

Is there any free HTML to PDF converter DLL available for ASP.NET 3.5?
If not what is the best and cheapest paid DLL available?

Comment: "Best" and "Cheapest" do **not** go hand in hand.

Comment: A better question would be *"What is the cheapest DLL that fullfills my requirements?"*. Since you haven't given any it makes it harder to answer properly.

Comment: I've been involved in doing HTML to PDF conversion for the past 4 years, and there are no free ones for C#, it's as simple as that. If you want free you have to write substantial amounts of code to get the free libraries working, most significantly the HTML renderer which is not a quick task

Comment: Can this be moved to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

1. [ExpertPDF HtmlToPdf Converter v6.0](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/)
2. [Others listed here...](http://wareseeker.com/free-pdfsharp-html-to-pdf/)
3. [PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)

I have personally worked with PDF Sharp which is easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

- [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-html.htm)
- [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)
- [web2pdfconvert](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/pdf-button.aspx) offers a web API